# Want to convert javascript code to php but return values mismatched

Tags: javascript, php, data-conversion

I am trying to convert below javascript code

```js
d1 = new Date("2022-01-13 00:00:00");
d2 = new Date();
d2.setTime(1641951202187.3433);  

console.log(d1,d2)
console.log(d1-d2); // returning value 60997813
```

PHP

```php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");   //India time (GMT+5:30)

$d1 = new DateTime("2022-1-13 00:00:00");
$mili = 1641951202187.3433;
$sec = $mili /1000;
$d = date('M-d-Y H:i:s',$sec);
$d2 = new Datetime($d);
$s1 = (strtotime($d1->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'))*1000)-(strtotime($d2->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'))*1000);

echo "Value of s1 =  ".$s1;
```

Returning 60998000 value which is mismatching with return value of javascript

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: I get `77197813` in Chrome from the JS

Comment: Very clear message [here](https://onlinephp.io/c/81486)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are passing a timestamp to `date` but date requires an integer timestamp so will trim away all milliseconds and microseconds.

You can parse a timestamp with fractional time up to microsecond accuracy using `DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u',$sec)` as for example in:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");   //India time (GMT+5:30)

$d1 = new DateTime("2022-1-13 00:00:00");

$mili = 1641951202187.3433;
$sec = $mili /1000;
$d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u',$sec);
$s1 = ($d1->getTimestamp()*1000)-($d2->format('U.u')*1000);

echo "Value of s1 =  ".$s1;
```

This will output 60997812.699951 and the discrepency is because (I think) because the last digit is beyond the accuracy of PHP so will be discarded.

Note: The format `U.u` stands for `timestamp in seconds.fraction in microseconds` and the microseconds fraction can be up to 6 digits. More details in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php)